# How to access AngularJS service methods from plain JavaScript (jQuery-Plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

## How to inject one javascript file into different Jquery-plugin to access the functions from javascript

**startTransactionController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('startTransactionCtrl', [
    '$scope',    
    'secondFileService',
function ($scope, secondFileService){
..
..
secondFileService.ICanAccessFunctionHere();
..
}
]);
```

**validateTransaction.js** --  *jQuery-Plugin*

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
     $.fn.validateTransaction = function( someObject ) {
        var _this =  this;
..
..
/*** secondFileService.ICanNotAccessFunctionHere();; ***/
Here, how can I call this function ???
..
..
}
})(jQuery);
```

In the validateTransaction.js, how can I inject the dependency of  secondFileService to call the function ?? Like I did in the startTransactionController.js

Comment: Why would you use angular function in jquery anonymous function? Angular services can be used within angular modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get("secondFileService").ICanAccessFunctionHere()
```

Also, you can find these useful:

`angular.element(domElement).scope()` to get the current scope of the element

`angular.element(domElement).injector()` to get the current app injector/services

`angular.element(domElement).controller()` to get a hold of the ng-controller instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getScript("PathToFile/validateTransaction.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
```